# Timeit return statement explanation

Tags: python, timing, timeit

I run `timeit` module as follow:-

```
%timeit  j2j.convert(input, rules)
```

It returns the output as

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.3 µs per loop
```

What does the return statement mean?

Comment: Also see [the `%timeit` documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit). And for [the `timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#basic-examples).

Comment: If that's not enough, please explain which part of it you don't understand.

Comment: Basically, what;s `10000` loops? what is `66.3us`? Is it the average of best of 3 execution time?

Comment: Did you read the docs? Or the answers to the linked question?

Comment: I can answer briefly, but it's going to be less clear than in docs or an answer: It ran your statement 10000 times. It did that 3 times, and kept the best of 3 runs. The `66.3 µs per loop` means that, in that best run, the average time to execute your statement was 66.3µs—that is, the total time to execute your statement 10000 times was 663ms, but it's been nice and done the division by 10000 for you.